# Android spinning progress bar

Tags: android, android-activity, progressdialog

I need help with Android spinning progress bar. I'm trying to make app where user have to sign up and log in and I wanted to show spinning bar with dark cube in background when data is sending.
The problem is that I need to create this spinning bar in many activities, so my question is: Is it possible to create new activity with only this spinning bar inside it and when I need it turn on this activity so it's overlapping my existing Activity and turn it off when I don't need it anymore? And I don't want to make it with Dialog, but simply this spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for an example of how to create a spinning progress bar: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_loading_spinner.htm

You can create an activity with only a ProgressBar in it by defining it as the only thing in the manifest.

When your progress is finished, change the activity with intents, see here for that: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html